# What is the best way to make operations around Spring AOP without affecting the main flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I'm new to Spring AOP and I was asked to save logs to the DB according to several actions taken on the system (pretty big by the way with many controllers, services and entities) I managed to create several advices and get the data needed to save to the logs but I'm worried if some unexpected exception might occurs during my transactions, so my question is what's the best practice in this case to make sure the main flow continue even if there is an unexpected exception with the log saving? Do you think it would be a good idea to use Async and manage the logs saving in a different thread?

By the way an using @Around to get data before and after joinpoint flow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Either use a combination of `@Before` and `@After` advice if you do not need to carry state from the former to the latter.
2. Or otherwise use an `@Around` advice with this basic structure:

```java
@Around("<your pointcut>")
public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  try {
    // 1. Do something before proceeding to the target method (optional)
    // 2. Proceed to target method (optional)
    Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
    // 3. Do something after obtaining original result (optional)
    // 4. Return original or modified result
    return result;
  }
  catch (...) {
    // Handle and/or log exception (optional), then either
    //   - re-throw original exception,
    //   - wrap it in another exception or
    //   - return a regular value
  }
  finally {
    // Do whatever needs to be done, no matter if an error occurs or not
  }
}
```